# Add a row similar to previous row in my webgrid in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am facing issue with adding a new row to my Webgrid. My Webgrid data has a dropdownlist in each column. When i click a button to add a new row it must repeat the same format of row. 
Pasting my webgrid code here. Please help me with it as im new to asp.net mvc

```
 <div id="grid1">
            @wg1.GetHtml(
    tableStyle: "gridTable",
    headerStyle: "gridHead",
            rowStyle: "gridRow",
    footerStyle: "gridFooter",
            alternatingRowStyle: "gridAltRow",
            htmlAttributes: new { id = "TableGrid" },
    columns: wg1.Columns(
    wg1.Column("Condition", format: @item => Html.DropDownList("Condition", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.SourceTableModel[0].Condition, "Select Condition", new { style = "width:100px", @class = "Condition" })),
    wg1.Column("SourceTable1", format: @item => Html.DropDownList("SourceTable1", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.SourceTableModel[0].SourceTableName, "Select Source 1", new { style = "width:100px", @class = "SourceTablea" })),
    wg1.Column("ColumnNames", format: @item => Html.DropDownList("ColumnNames", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Select Column", new { id = string.Empty, style = "width:100px", @class = "field1" })),
    wg1.Column("Operator", format: @item => Html.DropDownList("Operator", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.SourceTableModel[0].Operator, "Select Operator", new { style = "width:100px", @class = "Operator" })),
    wg1.Column("SourceTable1", format: @item => Html.DropDownList("SourceTable1", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.SourceTableModel[0].SourceTableName, "Select Source 2", new { style = "width:100px", @class = "SourceTablea" })),
    wg1.Column("ColumnNames", format: @item => Html.DropDownList("ColumnName", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Select Column", new { id = string.Empty, style = "width:100px", @class = "field1" })),
    wg1.Column("Condition", format: @item => Html.DropDownList("Condition", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.SourceTableModel[0].Condition, "Select Condition", new { style = "width:100px", @class = "Condition" }))
    )
    )
        </div>
<td>
        <input type="submit" value="Add Contact" id="ClickToAdd" />
```

My Javascript is as follow:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#ClickToAdd').click(function () {
    var newrow = "<tr><td> @wg1.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new { id = "TableGrid" },columns: wg1.Columns(wg1.Column("Condition", format: @item => Html.DropDownList("Condition", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.SourceTableModel[0].Condition, "Select Condition", new { style = "width:100px", @class = "Condition" })), wg1.Column("SourceTable1", format: @item => Html.DropDownList("SourceTable1", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.SourceTableModel[0].SourceTableName, "Select Source 1", new { style = "width:100px", @class = "SourceTablea" })), wg1.Column("ColumnNames", format: @item => Html.DropDownList("ColumnNames", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Select Column", new { id = string.Empty, style = "width:100px", @class = "field1" })), wg1.Column("Operator", format: @item => Html.DropDownList("Operator", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.SourceTableModel[0].Operator, "Select Operator", new { style = "width:100px", @class = "Operator" })), wg1.Column("SourceTable1", format: @item => Html.DropDownList("SourceTable1", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.SourceTableModel[0].SourceTableName, "Select Source 2", new { style = "width:100px", @class = "SourceTablea" })), wg1.Column("ColumnNames", format: @item => Html.DropDownList("ColumnName", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Select Column", new { id = string.Empty, style = "width:100px", @class = "field1" })),wg1.Column("Condition", format: @item => Html.DropDownList("Condition", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.SourceTableModel[0].Condition, "Select Condition", new { style = "width:100px", @class = "Condition" }))))</div></td></tr>";
    $("#webgrid tbody: last").append(newrow);
})
</script>
```

My edited webgrid is as follow:

```
@{
WebGrid wg1 = new WebGrid(Model.SourceTableModel);

}

<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div id="grid1">
            @wg1.GetHtml(
    tableStyle: "gridTable",
    headerStyle: "gridHead",
            rowStyle: "gridRow",
    footerStyle: "gridFooter",
            alternatingRowStyle: "gridAltRow",
            htmlAttributes: new { id = "TableGrid" },
    columns: wg1.Columns(
    wg1.Column("Condition", format: @item => Html.DropDownList("Condition", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.SourceTableModel[0].Condition, "Select Condition", new { style = "width:100px", @class = "Condition" })),
    wg1.Column("SourceTable1", format: @item => Html.DropDownList("SourceTable1", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.SourceTableModel[0].SourceTableName, "Select Source 1", new { style = "width:100px", @class = "SourceTablea" })),
    wg1.Column("ColumnNames", format: @item => Html.DropDownList("ColumnNames", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Select Column", new { id = string.Empty, style = "width:100px", @class = "field1" })),
    wg1.Column("Operator", format: @item => Html.DropDownList("Operator", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.SourceTableModel[0].Operator, "Select Operator", new { style = "width:100px", @class = "Operator" })),
    wg1.Column("SourceTable1", format: @item => Html.DropDownList("SourceTable1", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.SourceTableModel[0].SourceTableName, "Select Source 2", new { style = "width:100px", @class = "SourceTablea" })),
    wg1.Column("ColumnNames", format: @item => Html.DropDownList("ColumnName", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Select Column", new { id = string.Empty, style = "width:100px", @class = "field1" })),
    wg1.Column("Condition", format: @item => Html.DropDownList("Condition", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.SourceTableModel[0].Condition, "Select Condition", new { style = "width:100px", @class = "Condition" }))
    )
    )
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>


    </tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="submit" value="Add Contact" id="ClickToAdd" />
        <input type="submit" id="submitbutton1" value="Save" />
       @using (Html.BeginForm("WhereView", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
       {
        <input type="submit" id="nextbutton" value="Next" />
       }
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

respective javascript for dynamically adding new row :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#ClickToAdd').click(function () {
    var newrow = $("#webgrid tbody tr:last").clone();
    $("#webgrid tbody").append(newrow);
})
</script>
```

It didnt work as expected

Comment: Show the code you have tried.

Comment: @StephenMuecke i have tried using a jquery with the var for adding new row but it doesnt work

Comment: Show what you have tried and we can fix it for you. - you can get the last row using say `$('#grid1').find('tr').last()` and copy it using `.clone()` and add the copy using `.append()`

Comment: @StephenMuecke i have edited it in the code above

Comment: You have not really explained what is not working. If your just wanting to copy the last row you could use `var newrow = $("#webgrid tbody tr:last").clone(); $("#webgrid tbody).append(newrow);`

Comment: @StephenMuecke for the webgrid i have added the javascript wasnt working... the javascript needs to add a new row inside the webgrid on my view

Comment: Yes, but what is not working? Are you getting any error messages. Does the value of `newrow` return what you expect it to? You will have a much better chance of getting the correct answer if you explain the issue :)

Comment: I have edited the code... i am not getting a new row from the javascript as required ... that is the issue

Comment: Do you actually have an element with `id="webgrid"`? (all I can see in your view is a div with `id="grid1"`)

Comment: yes i figured... totally my fault.... now it works... thank you so much :)

Comment: Which means you would have seen an error in the console. You really need to learn the basics of debugging your javascript :)